# AWS: Can we configure request throttling in ELB/ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

We have an Application Load Balancer running on AWS which is receiving requests from third party application.

We want to throttle the request coming at ALB. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes but not with ALB itself.
We need to place API Gateway between your users and ALB that will perform throttling.